# Kernel panic after updating Linux server 16.04.2

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel, updates

I updated 7 packages on my Linux server 
`'apport libexpat1 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic python3-apport python3-problem-repore'`.
After the update, when I reboot the system, it shows me kernel panic. [kernel panic image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPLUW.jpg)

I think the problem is with the version. When I ran the kernel 4.4.0-62 from grub loader it worked fine but when I loaded with 4.4.0-83 it showed kernel panic.

Right now, I have to press 'Shift' every time I start my computer to load the previous kernel but I don't want to keep doing this. So I would like to:

- Uninstall the updated kernel

or

- Select the previous kernel as default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to remove the new kernel, boot up in the previous kernel.

then type `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.4.0-83`

or if you have aptitude, it gives you a text based interface for selecting packages. "_" is the key for purging packages. "g" to execute selections.